# count product qty in sub document mongodb transaction in one month

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

below is just an example of my mongodb documents. and `sum` the product qty in every transaction documents in I expected `175` when select transaction `August` from product documents

the expected result in `products` documents

```
[
 {
   "_id":"61012014f7416b0a41db7055",
   "name":"MIE",
   "retailPrice":20000,
   "qtyInTransaction":175
 }
]
```

here is my document

`products` document

```json
[
 {
   "_id":"61012014f7416b0a41db7055",
   "name":"MIE",
   "retailPrice":20000,
   "description":"PRODUK BARU",
 }
]
```

`producutInTransaction` document

```json
 [
  {
    "_id":"6106a3b1f1bbd62640c7b404",
    "transactionDate":{"$date":"2021-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"},
    "productsInTransactions":
         [
            {
             "_id":"6106a3cff1bbd62640c7b405",
             "productId":"61012014f7416b0a41db7055"},
             "qty":100,
             "price":5000,
             "description":"asdn"
           },
            {
             "_id":"6106a3cff1bbd62640c7b406",
             "productId":"61012014f7416b0a41db7055"},
             "qty":50,
             "price":5000,
             "description":"asdn"
           }

       ]
   },
  {
    "_id":"6106a3b1f1bbd62640c7b4007",
    "transactionDate":{"$date":"2021-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"},
    "productsInTransactions":
         [
            {
             "_id":"6106a3cff1bbd62640c7b407",
             "productId":"61012014f7416b0a41db7055"},
             "qty":25,
             "price":5000,
             "description":"asdn"
           },

       ]
   }

]
```

Thanks for any help, and sorry for my English

Comment: Do you want data from the last 30 days or the current month?

Comment: hi @J.F. thanks, maybe I forget to explain it, and data in the current month is  I need to take from the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query (adding `ISODate` value on whatever you want:

- First `$match` by `transactionData` which has to be "greater than or equal" to desired date. Here you have to calculate your date using JS and use the variable.
- Then `$unwind` `productsInTransactions` field to deconstruct the array.
- `$group` by `productId` and `$sum` the `qty` value.
- Later, `$lookup` to "join" with "product" collection and generate `data` field with desired values.
- And least `$project` to shown only fields you want.

```
db.productInTransaction.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "transactionDate": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2021-07-01T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$productsInTransactions"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$productsInTransactions.productId",
      "qty": {
        "$sum": "$productsInTransactions.qty"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "product",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$data.name",
          0
        ]
      },
      "retailPrice": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$data.retailPrice",
          0
        ]
      },
      "qtyInTransaction": "$qty"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c783nZ5AR8Z)

Result is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61012014f7416b0a41db7055",
    "name": "MIE",
    "qtyInTransaction": 175,
    "retailPrice": 20000
  }
]
```